# what is the area of triangle?

Tags: geometry

let 2s be the perimeter  of  a triangle, where s>0 is a fixed constant . what is the maximum possible value of the area of the triangle?

i was trying this question many times , but i could not get it. i was thinking that maximum area will be equilateral  triangle.  But i don't know how  to define that the maximum area of the triangle?

if anbody help me i would be very thankful to him.

Answer (score 3):

we have $$\sqrt[3]{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\le \frac{3s-(a+b+c)}{3}=\frac{s}{3}$$ thus $$(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\le \frac{s^3}{27}$$ multiplying by $s>0$ we get
$$s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\le \frac{s^4}{27}$$ taking the squareroot of both sides
$$\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\le \frac{s^2}{3\sqrt{3}}$$ therefore
$$A\le \frac{s^2}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: It is worth pointing out in your use of the AM-GM inequality that one has equality if and only if the three terms are all equal, so the bound you achieve is sharp and is only attained for an equilateral triangle.

Comment: thanks u so much @ Dr . sonnhard Graubner